# Flickr SDK is not converted in to the ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, flickr

I want to integrate the flickr api to upload the image through my iphone application to flickr site. I had downloaded the code snap&Runfrom github. i had integrated the same SDK code in my project.But it is showing me the error while convert in to the ARC. i had getting read line issues. 
Those errors are in  OFUtilities.m file

```
  static NSData *OFSha1(NSData *inData)
{
NSMutableData *result = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_SHA1_CTX context;
CC_SHA1_Init(&context);
CC_SHA1_Update(&context, [inData bytes], (CC_LONG)[inData length]);
CC_SHA1_Final([result mutableBytes], &context);
return result;
}
```

**In above method i have getting this error "No Matching Function for call CC_SHA1_Final"**

```
NSString *OFHMACSha1Base64(NSString *inKey, NSString *inMessage)
{
NSData *keyData = [inKey dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if ([keyData length] > CC_SHA1_BLOCK_BYTES) {
    keyData = OFSha1(keyData);
}

if ([keyData length] < CC_SHA1_BLOCK_BYTES) {
    NSUInteger padSize = CC_SHA1_BLOCK_BYTES - [keyData length];

    NSMutableData *paddedData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:keyData];
    [paddedData appendData:[NSMutableData dataWithLength:padSize]];
    keyData  = paddedData;
}

NSMutableData *oKeyPad = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA1_BLOCK_BYTES];
NSMutableData *iKeyPad = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA1_BLOCK_BYTES];

const uint8_t *kdPtr = [keyData bytes];
uint8_t *okpPtr = [oKeyPad mutableBytes];
uint8_t *ikpPtr = [iKeyPad mutableBytes];

memset(okpPtr, 0x5c, CC_SHA1_BLOCK_BYTES);
memset(ikpPtr, 0x36, CC_SHA1_BLOCK_BYTES);

NSUInteger i;
for (i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_BLOCK_BYTES; i++) {
    okpPtr[i] = okpPtr[i] ^ kdPtr[i];
    ikpPtr[i] = ikpPtr[i] ^ kdPtr[i];
}

NSData *msgData = [inMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableData *innerData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:iKeyPad];
[innerData appendData:msgData];
NSData *innerDataHashed = OFSha1(innerData);

NSMutableData *outerData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:oKeyPad];
[outerData appendData:innerDataHashed];

NSData *outerHashedData = OFSha1(outerData);


size_t outputLength;
char *outputBuffer = NewBase64Encode([outerHashedData bytes], [outerHashedData length], true, &outputLength);

NSString *result = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:outputBuffer length:outputLength encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
free(outputBuffer);
return result;
}
```

**here i had getting the error is"canot initialize a variable of type 'const uint8_t' with an r value of type const value"**

Please help me. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the conversion of a **non arc** code to **arc**  wont be a success. If your external framework doesn't support ARC, its better do not try for the conversion. instead set the compiler flag   **-fno-objc-arc** for that specific files to compile without ARC.

Comment: thanks for your reply .But here i have integrated the flickr snap&run code in to the other project instead of converting in to the ARC it had getting those errors